# Splitting string in VB.NET produces unusual results

Tags: vb.net

I am using the Split function in VB.NET, and it is producing a weird result when I display the output.

I have an XML document, and I just want to loop through each `<backup>` tag in the document, so I am using:

```
Dim XMLString As String
XMLString = "<backup>INFO</backup><backup>ANOTHER INFO</backup>"

Dim SplitBackup As String()
SplitBackup = XMLString.Split("<backup>")

For Each BackupContent In SplitBackup
    MsgBox(BackupContent)
Next
```

Now, one would expect this to output INFO in a MsgBox, I click OK and then another one would popup and show 'ANOTHER INFO', but it seems that the Split function is getting stuffed up with the '<' and '>' in it. Is there someway I can get around this by escaping it, or parsing it some other way.

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: .NET has built in XML parsing utilities. A good place to start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bcctyt8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yeah thats good, but I would rather use the Split thing so I don't have to try and learn the XML thing - thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @JordanS your consideration is not correct! Sooner or later you will have to handle XML structures and `String.Split` is not going to work well. The time you will spend learning the build-in XML handling will pay off.

Comment: @pasty is correct.  It took me some time to get the basics down but it was worth the effort.  I added an answer that shows a simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility to do this is to use [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to split the tags (and escape the problematic symbols) and then use [LINQ to Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx) to get the value from each tag:

```
Dim XMLString As String = "<backup>INFO</backup><backup>ANOTHER INFO</backup>"
Dim words = Regex.Split(XmlString, "\<backup\>").Where(function(f) not String.IsNullOrEmpty(f)).Select(function(f) f.Replace("</backup>", String.Empty))    ' 
for each word in words
    Console.WriteLine(word)
next word
```

The output is:

```
INFO
ANOTHER INFO
```

What the code does:

```
Dim words = Regex
                ' split on every tag
                .Split(XmlString, "\<backup\>")
                ' remove empty items
                .Where(function(f) not String.IsNullOrEmpty(f))
                ' remove trailing closing tag and thus retrieve the value within
                .Select(function(f) f.Replace("</backup>", String.Empty))
```

As already suggested you better learn how to use the build-in XML support - it is easier and safer because you do not need to pay attention to the brackets - `<` and `>` are automatically handled. A possible solution could look like this (**! you need to have a valid XML structure - one unique root node!**):

```
' !!! you need to have a valid XML element - one root node !!!
Dim XMLString As String = "<root><backup>INFO</backup><backup>ANOTHER INFO</backup></root>"
dim words = XDocument.Parse(XMLString).Root.Descendants("backup").Select(function (f) f.Value)

for each word in words
    Console.WriteLine(word)
next word
```

The output is the same as above. How does the code work:

```
dim words = XDocument
                ' parse the specified XML structure; use Load("file.xml") to load from file
                .Parse(XMLString)
                ' from the root node
                .Root
                ' take all nodes matching the specified tag
                ' note - no need to pay attention to the < and >
                .Descendants("backup")
                ' select the value of the XML node
                .Select(function (f) f.Value)
```

Comment: Glad that the answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

Give XML a chance.

```
    Dim bups As XElement = <backups><backup>INFO</backup><backup>ANOTHER INFO</backup></backups>
    For Each xe As XElement In bups.Elements
        Debug.WriteLine(xe.Value)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get rid of the close element.

So you could use:

```
Dim XMLString As String
XMLString = "<backup>INFO</backup><backup>ANOTHER INFO</backup>"

Dim SplitBackup As String()
SplitBackup = XMLString.Split("<backup>")

For Each BackupContent In SplitBackup
    Dim Something() as string
    Something = BackupContent.Split("</backup">)
    MsgBox(Something(0))
Next
```

Not the most elegant coding though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, ill give it a go when I get back to the right computer

Comment: @JordanS: You'll probably want to either use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` in the second call to `Split`, or check for empty strings before using them.